# Play button in HTML form not playing the latest audio file, plays an old version that is meant to have been overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio, browser-cache

I have built a webpage that sends the text entered in a form to a Node.js server that synthesizes an audio file `speech.wav` and stores it in `/public` folder. When I go to `localhost:8000` and the page loads for the first time, I can enter text, submit, and click on the play button to play the correct audio. Script for playing the file is

```
function playAudio() {
  var audioFile = new Audio('./speech.wav');
  audioFile.play()
}
```

Code for Play button is

```
          <div class="d-grid col-3">
            <button type="button" value="sound" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="playAudio()"
              id="playbutton">Play</button>
          </div>
```

But when I enter some different text in the same page for the *second time* and submit, pressing the play button plays the **old speech** again and again. However, I noticed that the server correctly synthesized and stored the new speech audio in `speech.wav`, deleting the previous one. (I checked by going to the directory and playing it with Windows media player.)
Opening another tab and going to `localhost:8000` and straightaway clicking the play button surprisingly plays the new speech! But in the previous tab it would still play the old speech. I have tried this on Chrome, Edge and Chrome for android.

I am unable to pinpoint where this bug arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a caching issue, you can resolve like this:

```
function playAudio() {
  var audioFile = new Audio('./speech.wav?' + new Date().getTime());
  audioFile.play()
}
```

As @fdcpp mentions below, using the `private` mode of your browser during development will eliminate caching issues. However in production (if you are changing the file while keeping the name the same) the `?time` method is a quick fix

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved the issue! 
Do you have a link to any article explaining why this works?

I had added to the head the following lines but apparently they didn't work:
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

Comment: those `meta`tags work for the web page itself, but have nothing to do with external files. By changing the `?search` to a unique string (`new Date().getTime()` will always be unique) it effectively tells the browser to '_get a new file you have never seen before_'

Comment: Although this works and is quite a fun solution, would it not be best to advise that a browser should be used in private mode for testing?

Comment: @fdcpp good point - OP didn't clarify and I assumed production. will update answer

Comment: It's in development stage only. I had tried on Incognito mode of Chrome before the fix, the problem was still there. Maybe because opening a page in private mode does create a temporary cache, which is deleted only after closing the window.